# Start and Stop Python Script from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x

How can I start and stop a python script from a NodeJS server? I have seen the module "python-shell", but it doesn't provide a way to kill the script after running it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Example from [the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('python3', ['script.py']);

child.on('close', (code, signal) => {
  console.log(
    `child process terminated due to receipt of signal ${signal}`);
});

// Send SIGTERM to process
child.kill('SIGTERM');
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what the 'child.on' function is doing?

Comment: It declares a callback. **On** a `close` event, it will call the associated function, which prints a message to the console.